# Highchart: Irrelevent YAxis Scale at the end

Tags: highcharts, scale

Highchart is adding irrelevant y-axis scale at the end, when the max value is more than 80.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qa1hv5bq/1/

```
            $(function() {
                function draw() {
                    if ($('div[data-sectionId="8766"] .chart .highcharts-container').length > 0) return;
                    $('div[data-sectionId="8766"] .chart').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: 'AgendaW01-Medium',
                                fontSize: '8pt'
                            },
                            height: 90,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                            spacing: [0, 5, 5, 0],
                            type: 'bar',
                        },
                        xAxis: [{
                            categories: ['3%', '96%', '2%'],
                            labels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontFamily: 'AgendaW01-Medium',
                                    fontSize: '8pt',
                                    color: '#000000'
                                }
                            },
                            tickLength: 0
                        }, {
                            categories: ['Europe ex UK', 'UK', 'Money Market'],
                            labels: {
                                align: 'left',
                                x: 0,
                                step: 1,
                                style: {
                                    fontFamily: 'AgendaW01-Medium',
                                    fontSize: '8pt',
                                    color: '#000000'
                                }
                            },
                            offset: 250,
                            tickLength: 0
                        }],
                        yAxis: {
                            gridLineColor: '#7f7f7f',
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            },
                            plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                color: '#7f7f7f',
                                width: 1,
                                zIndex: 10
                            }],
                            labels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontFamily: 'AgendaW01-Medium',
                                    fontSize: '8pt',
                                    color: '#7f7f7f'
                                },
                                overflow: 'justify',
                                format: '{value}%',
                                y: 8
                            }
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            bar: {
                                animation: false,
                                color: '#375789',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: {
                                pointWidth: 20,
                                stacking: 'normal',
                                pointPadding: 0.1,
                                groupPadding: 0
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            data: [3, 96, 2]
                        }, {
                            xAxis: 1,
                            data: [0, 0, 0]
                        }],
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        legend: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    });
                };
                if ($('div[data-sectionId="8766"]').closest('.tab').length == 0) {
                    draw();
                    return;
                }
                var containingTab = $('div[data-sectionId="8766"]').closest('.tab');
                var containingTabs = $(containingTab).closest('.tabs');
                containingTabs.tabs('onChange', containingTab.index(), function() {
                    draw();
                });
            });
```

In the attached example the scale 110% is something we did not expect. Does any one have any idea on how to remove this. This additional scale only comes up when the max value crosses 80%.

We do not want to set the max value for reasons below
1.  The max value is dynamic, there are cases it might be like 5-6% and setting the max to a fixed value will not go well.
2.  We do not want to set the max value same as the data max.

Thanks,
Sarath

Comment: While fetching data, if your data is in sorted order you may put data[0] means first point as min and data[data.length-1] as max value i.e your last value dynamically

Comment: The problem with setting max value is that the max bar will always be displayed till the edge of the chart. Want to avoid this to give the chart a better look & feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) as 0 on yAxis.

```
yAxis:{
   maxPadding:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback argument of `highcharts()` function to check if the max generated value for `yAxis` is greater than 100. If yes then you set it to 100, else you do nothing:

```
$('div[data-sectionId="8766"] .chart').highcharts({
    /* ... */
}, function (chart) {
    if (chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max > 100) {
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            max: 100
        });
    }
});
```

See a working JSFiddle here (with a data max equal to 99) : http://jsfiddle.net/qa1hv5bq/2/